# Regex expression

Tags: regex, vb.net, recursion

i have a string similar to this one:

```
Hi, <<\name>> <<\surname>>, this is an example <<\test>>.
```

I what a regex that match and split this string in:

```
"Hi, " 
<<\name>>
" "
<<\surname>> 
", this is an example " 
<<\test>>
"."
```

I tried this one: `(<<\*.*?>>)|(>>*.*?<<)`, but doesn't work. It's possible?
Thanks.

Comment: is <<*.?>> a typo? it would be wrong. it's <<.*?>>

Comment: and what do you want to do with the (>>.*?<<) anyway? it doesn't help to your solution, does it? and probably even confuses the regex

Answer (score 2):

You could use this expression (it uses positive lookaheads and positive lookbehinds):

```
<<.*?>>|(?<=>>|^).*?(?=<<|$)
```

it matches strings surrounded by `<<` and `>>` symbols, strings which are between these symbols and strings from the begin to `<<` and to the end from `>>`.

You could find a `C#` example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/4IiUF).

Comment: Thank you very much Alex...that's was!
The only thing is, this regex doesn't much carriage return, but nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str =' Hi, <<\name>> <<\surname>>, this is an example <<\test>>.';
$old= array('<<','>>');
$new =array('"<<','>>"');
$str2=str_replace ($old,$new,$str);
//retruns Hi, "<<\name>>" "<<\surname>>", this is an example "<<\test>>".
```

Comment: maybe he's not developing in php?

Comment: sorry but i want split no replace. Im' developing in VB.NET